# Inbound email missing attachment?

Tags: apex, email, apex-email-service

I have a requirement to save attachment received from email in Salesforce object using Email To Salesforce. I tried using the below code but attachment are not getting saved, when I checked using the system.debug() it shows null value for both binaryattachment and testattachment.

Is there any setting that I need to check? I tested this with both text file and image file as attachment.

```
public class EmailProcess implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler 
{
  public Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.InboundEmail email, Messaging.Inboundenvelope envelope) 
  {
    system.debug('email.textAttachments:' + email.textAttachments); //null
    system.debug('email.binaryAttachments:' + email.binaryAttachments); //null
    List<Attachment> attList = new List<Attachment>();
    //Assigned parentId 
    system.debug('parentId' +  parentId); //Shows record Id
    for (Messaging.Inboundemail.BinaryAttachment file : email.binaryAttachments) 
    {
      Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
      attachment.Name = file .fileName;
      attachment.Body = file .body;
      // some hardcoded or id extracted from email reference
      attachment.ParentId = parentId;
      attList .add(attachment);
   }
   if(attList .size()>0)
   {
     insert attList;
   }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you add (or edit) the email handler class via the email service definition you get a choice of what sort of attachments should be passed to it as shown below. Check that setting.

[image: email service page]