# Associate Incoming Email to a Specific Record

Tags: email

We have a need to have an email address which will associate incoming emails/attachments to a specific record in Salesforce.  Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: What have you researched so far? About the only idea I can come up with is an [inbound email service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_inbound_what_is.htm).

Comment: I have successfully configured Salesforce to have an email address that will receive incoming email & create a record in a custom object based on the email.  I am having a problem in that it seems like the binary attachments are being stripped off of the email.  When I use apex to check for the existence of a binary attachment that I know was with the email when it was sent, I get a NULL result.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution posted elsewhere ([Inbound email missing attachment?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/47677/inbound-email-missing-attachment)).  There is a setting in Email Services that specifies what kind of attachments to allow.

Answer (score 2):

you can use global class Messaging.InboundEmailHandler and checked sender email address to contact email address if both are same then you can store the data and attachment.

```
 global class EmailAsso implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler {

global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.InboundEmail email,
Messaging.InboundEnvelope envelope) {

 Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailresult();

 String fName = email.fromname.substring(0,email.fromname.indexOf(' '));
 String lName = email.fromname.substring(email.fromname.indexOf(' '));


 Contact c = [Select Id, Name, Email, AccountId From Contact Where Email = :email.fromAddress Limit 1];        

if (email.binaryAttachments != null && email.binaryAttachments.size() > 0) {
  for (integer i = 0 ; i < email.binaryAttachments.size() ; i++) {
    Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
    attachment.ParentId = c.Id;
    attachment.Name = email.binaryAttachments[i].filename;
    attachment.Body = email.binaryAttachments[i].body;
    insert attachment;
  }
}

return result;

  }

}
```